# AWK Replace pattern at specific line trough passing variables

Tags: variables, awk, line

I am trying to pass two variables to awk in order to replace a word **(-v var1)** with a space **(" ")** at specific line **(-v var2)**. When I ran it, nothing is replaced at the line I wanted.

My first approach to do it is:

```
palabra=betina; i=5 ; awk -v var1="$i" -v var2="$palabra" 'NR==var1 {sub("var2"," ")}{print }' Countries > tmp
```

on the file *"Countries"*, with content is:

```
usa
usa
colombia
spain
betina
```

Comment: In the description, you say `var1` is the word and `var2` is the line, but in the command you're using them the other way around.

Comment: Rather than explicitly writing an action of `{print}`, it is more idiomatic to use a pattern of `1`.  eg `'NR==var1 {sub("var2"," ")} 1'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `var2` and you should be good.

```
palabra=betina; i=5 ; awk -v var1="$i" -v var2="$palabra" 'NR==var1 {sub(var2," ")}{print }' file
```